# Unity - How to keep an object at the right or left of another object

Tags: unity

I created a WallCheckRight and a WallCheckLeft linked to my character.
However, I noticed that when my character do a flip, they switch place (right to left and left to right)

[image]

Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

1) The easiest way to prevent that instead of changing animations like what Shraa has mentioned, is to restructure your hierarchy.

[image]

You only want to flip the scale of PlayerSpriteRenderer.

OR

2) Instead of using a empty gameObject's transforms to store left and right points, do it in code.

```
Vector3 rightWallCheck = transform.position + Vector3.right;
Vector3 leftWallCheck = transform.position + Vector3.left;
```

Answer (score 0):

What flipping does is just change the scale from 1 to -1 (or whatever the value). So all colliders and children will have this effect that you're having.

What you could do is have animations for the player facing both right and left direction. Instead of flipping using scale, you can just switch between the animations.

Edit: Instead of changing animations, which will need you to have more sprites which may decrease performance and increase size, you should use the solution that Eclmist suggested